# Regex in PHP to change usernames to pretty links

Tags: php, regex

I am using a PHP regular expression to change usernames to pretty links in text.
Firstly, It looks for an `@ sign`,
Secondly, It checks if the `@ sign` has a user id touching it, E.G. `@User10`,
Thirdly, It makes sure that the user id is between 1 and 20 characters,
Fourthly it makes the links pretty.

This is my Regex

```
/(?<=^|\s|[([])\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/
```

This regex works fine for these text examples

```
@User1 This is a test string @User2
@User3
```

But it does not work in these text examples

```
<br>@User1 Hello John@User2
```

All of these Users should be matched but they are not being matched if a string is touching the `@ sign` before it.

I have an online regex example set here.
http://regex101.com/r/zK9kC4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this expression on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

```
/@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/
```

It matches all criteria you have given for the User-Id's.

Comment: `@UserWithMoreThen20Characters`

Answer (score 2):

> All of these `Users` should be `matched` but they are not being matched if a string is touching the @ sign before it.

Why can't you just remove your **Positive Lookbehind** and use the following?

```
/@(\w{1,20})\b/
```

**Note**: `\w` matches any (`letter`, `number` or `underscore`) which is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and with ending with a word boundary `\b` it will not match user id's with more than `20` characters.

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/dR9qG9)

Comment: user id should be between 1 and 20 characters. What about a `\b` after that thing? wouldn't this match a user id longer then 20 too?

Comment: @Jonny5 OP didn't specify but I added it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `/@([^@\s]+)/`, for example:

```
$string = preg_replace('/@([^@\s]+)/', '<a href="/$1">@$1</a> ', $string);
```

Online demo: http://regex101.com/r/iD1oN1

Answer (score 0):

If you get rid of the `^` in your regex, it successfully identifies all four of your examples.  The `^` character requires the next character `@` to start the line.